# @LocalServerPort missing from Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I upgraded my app from spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE to 2.0.0.RELEASE, and I can no longer import `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.LocalServerPort`. I was using this to inject the port the server is running on during a test:

```
public class Task1Test {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
```

The [Spring release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes) do not mention this removal and [@LocalServerPort was not deprecated](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.5.9.RELEASE/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/LocalServerPort.html).

Is there an equivalent in Spring Boot 2.0 that I can use?

**Edit**: I'm pretty sure that the class is gone. I'm getting these compilation errors:

```
[ERROR] ... Task1Test.java:[12,49]package org.springframework.boot.context.embedded does not exist
[ERROR] ... Task1Test.java:[46,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LocalServerPort
```

Comment: tired purging maven dependencies?

Comment: Thanks, your problem become my solution.  I am using "org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.LocalServerPort" instead of "org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort". it works!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like it was moved to [org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/LocalServerPort.html) without notice. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

@LocalServerPort is now in
***org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort***

Update your imports in the test code.

Relevant link to the Spring boot docs here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/server/LocalServerPort.html

the change is notified here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/LocalServerPort.html

Note that if you are using the Spring Boot Getting Started guides, the guides are still using the old namespace and hence you will see a build error without an option to fix. You will need to update this manually.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's been moved to `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency as per this [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/LocalServerPort.html) documentation.

Try adding this maven dependency to see if that fixes it

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```